# Elegant way to fetch custom tag in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Is here some elegant way to get and replace custom tags in string?

For example

```
"some long text [o:prop] and [u:date]"
```

Result array :

- "[o:prop]"
- "[u:date]"

Thanks

Comment: do you have a list of tags and their replacements?

Comment: yea, its my own tags and my function returns theirs replacements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"\[[a-z]:[a-z]{4}\]"
```

assumes 1 lowercase character followed by a colon, followed by four lowercase characters, all bounded by square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It's always risky, but you could go for some regex like:

```
"\\[(.*?)]"
```

with the *global modifier*.

Safer: `\\[(o:prop|u:date)]`

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes regex was my first idea, but regex is a bit unsafe as you say.

Comment: If you use it that way, it is. Though if you specify your list of tags within, it's not that much.

Comment: Care to explain why it's unsafe?

Comment: @BobVale you're not checking if the first [ was escaped for example. Could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense why its not safe. If OP is comparing the resulting values with a list of values then it's no more dangerous than your "safer" example

Comment: @BobVale not really. He could miss some in the first case. Example: `Some random text with a \[ blabla [o:prop]` will catch `[ blabla [o:prop]` and miss the real tag.

Comment: @Loamhoof, I see what you mean, a better generic solution that means you don't have to list the tags would be `@"\[[^[]*?]"`. The  escaping is irrelevant though because the safer method would still match `\[o:prop]`. It should be not safe if nesting rather than because of escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. use a regular expression.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Read. Learn. Apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string,string> {
    {"[o:prop]","FISH"},
      {"[u:date]","2013-04-12"}
};

var testString = "some long text [o:prop] and [u:date]";

var result= new Regex(@"\[[^[]*?]").Replace(
      testString,
      match => replacements.ContainsKey(match.Value) ? replacements[match.Value] : match.Value);
```

Comment: Don't use the dot star! (Won't work if the brackets are nested.) Guess what `\[.*?\]` matches when applied to the string: `"some long [text [o:prop] and] [a [u:date]]"`? Not what you think! A much faster and more accurate equivalent expression would be: `\[[^[\]]*\]`. Say what you mean - mean what you say.

Comment: @ridgerunner better? you don't need to exclude ] if you use the non greedy expression

Comment: Yes,`\[[^[]*?]` is much better than `\[.*?\]` - (it now matches innermost matching bracket pairs accurately). But the greedy `\[[^[\]]*\]` expression is much faster because it completes its match of the bracket contents in a single step. The lazy version must stop and look ahead (i.e. backtrack) before matching each and every character one at a time.